# dj allauth get password when its resetted

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-allauth

I need to provide the raw password of an allauth user to a third party provider when he resets his password. So everytime when the password gets resetted I call the `@receiver(password_reset)`. However, then the password was already salted. I need to get the raw password data to realise the password change also at an external service. How would get the new "raw" password, which wasn't already salted or how could I desalt it?

```
from allauth.account.signals import password_reset
from django.dispatch import receiver
@receiver(password_reset)
def password_change_callback(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
        #run third party api call containing the new password
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to get the new password a user inputed while changing his/her password. What you can do is that on the post request you store the value of the new password the user inputed in the form in a variable. This way after you have reseted the password you can still access the raw password since you saved it in a variable before resetting. So something like the below:

```
new_password = request.POST.get("new_password")
# your code to set the new password goes here
and after that you can still access the new_password variable and do whatever you want with it.
```

Comment: Where would I put this line of code?

Comment: right below 
def password_change_callback(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
just make sure to declare this variable before you reset the password

Comment: That's the problem.. The function gets called when the @receiver(password_reset) is triggered. That indicates that the password already has been reset succesful...

Comment: Is password_reset a function you created? if so share the code for that

Comment: It's imported from all auth: from allauth.account.signals import password_reset. See updated code

Comment: Try printing out, request.POST, use this to check what data is available, possibly the form data could still be accessed

Comment: I checked... The output is ´None´

Comment: In that case you will have to change the way you are implementing your change password, are you working with django rest framework or just django with a frontend?

Comment: I'm working also with DRF.

Comment: Is it maybe possible to add this variable to the allauth method directly, and return it later?

Comment: I'm using dj-rest-auth to communicate between drf and allauth

Comment: so is this function being called by the url for the form the user inputs their passwords?

Comment: It's an internat allauth function so I'm not sure. I dindn't wrote it, so I wonder how I can change it

Comment: to have more power and flexibility make you own change password view using serialisers since you are working with DRF

Answer (score 0):

```
class ChangeUserPasswordView(UpdateAPIView):

queryset = User.objects.filter(is_active=True)
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
serializer_class = ChangePasswordSerializer

def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.request.user
```

Then for the serializer

```
from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import validate_password

class ChangePasswordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
new_password = serializers.CharField(
    write_only=True, required=True, validators=[validate_password]
)
confirm_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
old_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ("old_password", "new_password", "confirm_password")

def validate_old_password(self, value):
    user = self.context["request"].user
    if not user.check_password(value):
        raise serializers.ValidationError(
            {"old_password": "Old password is not correct"}
        )

    return value

def validate(self, attrs):
    if attrs["new_password"] != attrs["confirm_password"]:
        raise serializers.ValidationError(
            {"password": "Password fields didn't match."}
        )

    return attrs

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.set_password(validated_data["new_password"])
    instance.save()

    return instance
```

In your user model add function

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password

    def check_password(self, raw_password, *args, **kwargs):
    return check_password(raw_password, self.password)
```

If you want a reset password, where you don’t want to add the old password you can replace your serilalizer code with the below.

```
class ChangePasswordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
new_password = serializers.CharField(
    write_only=True, required=True, validators=[validate_password]
)
confirm_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ("new_password", "confirm_password")


def validate(self, attrs):
    if attrs["new_password"] != attrs["confirm_password"]:
        raise serializers.ValidationError(
            {"password": "Password fields didn't match."}
        )

    return attrs

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.set_password(validated_data["new_password"])
    instance.save()

    return instance
```

Here in the serializer validate function you have access to the user's inputed password using

```
attrs["new_password"]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, how would I achieve this for a password reset?

Comment: this is for password reset, this can be used as change password or resetting a password. they are technically the same thing

Comment: Yes, however, the normal AllAuth Reset dosen't require an old password and sends an e-mail to the user. How can I use your serialized approach, so that its useable with the forgot password on the all auth sign in page?

Comment: in that case remove the old_password logic from the code, i will update my answer to have that code too